# How to get a linebreak for random generator results?

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I've been having this idea of creating a little generator that randomizes a hero to play and picks the items for dota. 
Long story short everything seems to be working so far, but I'm not sure how to get the results to be on seperate lines

The probably important part of the script:

```
        var randomNumber1 = parseInt(Math.random() * wordlist1.length);
        var randomNumber2 = parseInt(Math.random() * wordlist2.length);
        var randomNumber3 = parseInt(Math.random() * wordlist3.length);
        var randomNumber4 = parseInt(Math.random() * wordlist4.length);
        var randomNumber5 = parseInt(Math.random() * wordlist5.length);
        var randomNumber6 = parseInt(Math.random() * wordlist6.length);
        var randomNumber7 = parseInt(Math.random() * wordlist7.length);
        var hero = "Hero:" + wordlist1[randomNumber1];
        var boots = "Boots:" + wordlist2[randomNumber2];
        var item1 = "Item1:" + wordlist3[randomNumber3];
        var item2 = "Item2:" + wordlist4[randomNumber4];
        var item3 = "Item3:" + wordlist5[randomNumber5];
        var item4 = "Item4:" + wordlist6[randomNumber6];
        var item5 = "Item5:" + wordlist7[randomNumber7];

        var finalOutput = hero + " " + boots + " " + item1 + " " + item2 + " " + item3 + " " + item4 + " " + item5;
        //var name = wordlist1[randomNumber1] + " " + wordlist2[randomNumber2] + " " + wordlist3[randomNumber3] + " " + wordlist4[randomNumber4] + " " + wordlist5[randomNumber5] + " " + wordlist6[randomNumber6] + " " + wordlist7[randomNumber7];            

        //alert(name); //Remove first to slashes to alert the name

        //If there's already a name it is removed  
        if(document.getElementById("result")){
            document.getElementById("placeholder").removeChild(document.getElementById("result"));
        }
        // A div element is created to show the generated name. The Name is added as a textnode. Textnode is added to the placeholder.
        var element = document.createElement("div");
        element.setAttribute("id", "result");
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(finalOutput));
        document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(element);
    }       
</script>
```

Now what happens is that I get the result like this: Hero:Hero Boots:Boots Item1:Item1 etc.

What I want to get is this: 
Hero: Hero 
Boots: Boots 
Item1: Item1

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure this is Java?  It looks *a lot* like Javascript.

Comment: Assuming javascript, you need to use linebreak, <\br>.

Comment: Sounds like a css/html structure question, so please rename it.

Answer (score 2):

To create line breaks in HTML you need to create either a 
 element, or make paragraphs with the  tag. The resulting HTML would look like this:

```
Hero: Hero<br/>
Boots: Boots<br/>
Item1: Item1<br/>
```

or

```
<p>Hero: Hero</p>
<p>Boots: Boots</p>
<p>Item1: Item1</p>
```

I'd recommend reading up some basic HTML tutorials if you want to continue, there are lots of material on for example [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com)

Comment: Do I have to split up the output then? Since currently it just gives the output for var finalOutput. I tried var finalOutput = hero + "<br/>" + boots + etc., but it didn't recognize the break

Comment: The concept of finalOutput doesn't work, since you want to add several elements to the document, rather than making a string with all the text. There is a different between having the text "<br/>" in a string and adding it to the document as plain text, and adding a true <br/> element. You want the later.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, need to include `<br />` as the result is HTML, and `<br />` is HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

- Create an own paragraph element for each item
- use html linebreaks (`<br />`) and set the innerHTML of your #result div
- use linebreaks in the text (`\n`) and set the whitespace style of your div:

  ```
  div#result {
      white-space: pre;
      white-space: pre-line;
  }
  ```

Also, please make your script code shorter by using an array of wordlists:

```
// wordlists = [wordlist1, wordlist2, ...];
var finaloutput = wordlists.map( function(list, index) {
    var word =  list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
    if (index == 0)
        return "Hero: "+word;
    if (index == 1)
        return "Boots: "+word;
    return "Item"+(index-1)+": "+word;
 }).join("\n");
```